# Prime $p$ that results in a power of 2

Tags: prime-numbers

For every prime number $p$, the function ${\rm ms_2}(p)$ gives the smallest prime number that results in a power of 2 when added to $p$.

For example: ${\rm ms_2}(857) = 167$, since $857+167 = 1024 = 2^{10}$.

What is wrong with this Mathematica code?

```
ms2[n_] := Module[{p},
  Do[If[PrimeQ[p = NextPrime[n]] && 2^n - p == 1, Return[p]], {p, n + 1}]] ##
```

Comment: For one thing, you seem to have `p` ranging from `1` to `n+1` from the `Do`, but are also trying to assign `p` to be `NextPrime[n]` (which will never change). You probably don't want both of those.

Answer (score 2):

Another implementation using NestWhile:

```
f[p_]:=NestWhile[2 # &, 2^Ceiling[Log[2, p]], !PrimeQ[# - p] &] - p;
f[857]
f[859]
(*167*)
(*7333*)
```

Some primes have crazy large values:

```
plotData = Table[{i, f[i]}, {i, Prime[Range[285]]}];
ListLinePlot[plotData, PlotRange -> All, ScalingFunctions -> "Log"]
```

[image]

In fact, some are so large I haven't even gotten an answer:
`f[1871]` just runs indefinitely.

Comment: Thank you Ydd. One question: does your implementation consider 1 as a prime number? Because f[7]=1 and not the correct answer f[7]=549755813881 (7+549755813881=2^39). I appreciate the clarification.

Comment: @RubensVilhenaFonseca thanks for pointing this out. This arose from the fact I was checking at each nest level if `CompositeQ[# - p] &` and since 1 is neither composite nor prime, it would stop if the difference was 1. I changed it to `!PrimeQ[# - p]&` so this should only stop if the difference is Prime (which 1 is not). Apologies for that.

Comment: @RubensVilhenaFonseca there was also some issue with my plot where it wasn't actually plotting the values of `f`. I fixed my plot and you can see there are some primes where the value is so large it drowns out everything else in the plot, even in log scale!

Comment: ydd, thank you very much for your corrections.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to pinpoint exactly what is wrong because there are several weird things about your code and how you use variables.

Anyhow, keeping the same algorithmic approach, one could use `While` loop:

```
ms2[n_] := Module[{p = 1}, While[p = NextPrime[p]; ! IntegerQ[Log2[n + p]]]; p];

ms2[857]
(* 167 *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not NestWhile

```
f[n_] := NestWhile[NextPrime, 0, !IntegerQ[Log2[ # + n]]& ];
f[859]
```

> 7333

Comment: Thank you AsukaMinato. Would you know how long on average your implementation would take to give the answer for f[7]?